# Pandas fillna() does not apply values from one column to an entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Please explain, why this won't work (hc is pandas dataframe on below example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hc = pd.DataFrame([['Adolf', np.nan],
                  ['Hans', 'Johan']],
                  columns=('First Name', 'Second Name'))

hc.fillna(value=hc["First Name"])
```

> ```
> First Name    Second Name
> 0 Adolf   NaN
> 1 Hans    Johan
> ```

```
hc[['First Name','Second Name']].fillna(value=hc["First Name"])
```

> ```
> First Name    Second Name
> 0 Adolf   NaN
> 1 Hans    Johan
> ```

Using other column's value works only for one column like that:

```
hc['Second Name'].fillna(value=hc["First Name"],inplace=True)
hc
```

> ```
> First Name    Second Name
> 0 Adolf   Adolf
> 1 Hans    Johan
> ```

I wish to apply a value (mask value) from one column to NaN-s in the entire dataframe.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `hc.ffill(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with a Series as reference, per row.

```
hc = hc.fillna(hc['First Name'])
```

This is not currently supported on the columns for all pandas version (it is in the latest), but you can cheat using a double transpose to perform the operation on the rows:

```
hc = hc.T.fillna(hc['First Name']).T
```

output:

```
  First Name Second Name
0      Adolf       Adolf
1       Hans       Johan
```